# Routing generic urls to sections or structures urls

Tags: routes

I have a structure setup with parents and children.  Can a route be setup in the CP to route a generic url to a specific parent or child of the structure.  For example I have a blog landing page that is a child of the structure.  Can a route be setup, so when a user enters at /blog it takes them to that landing page?

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is create a structure `siteUrls` which is responsible for page urls. Top-level entries have url of `{slug}`, nested entries have url of `{parent.uri}/{slug}`. The top-level entry with slug *blog* will be the entry with url */blog*. Then you can have an entry type of `blogLandingPage` and use that entry type for this entry.

The other piece of the puzzle is getting the right template for the `blogLandingPage`. The trick for this is to use a feature of the [twig include tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html):

> New in version 1.2: The possibility to pass an array of templates has been added in Twig 1.2.
>
> You can also provide a list of templates that are checked for existence before inclusion. The first template that exists will be included:

So your template for  `siteUrls` will look like:

```
{% include ['_siteUrls/'~entry.type, '_siteUrls/default'] %}
```

And the template for entries (like this one) with type `blogLandingPage` is *_siteUrls/blogLandingPage*. Using a list for the `{% include %}` means some entry types can share templates, and thing fail more gracefully if you have an entry type without a matching template.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure I follow what you're trying to do, but here's what I'd suggest (based on my interpretation)...

1. Create an actual template, either `blog.html` or `blog/index.html`.
2. In that template, write a couple simple lines of Twig code which will (A) determine which page they are supposed to be routed to, then (B) [redirect to that page](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect).

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. The client would like control over creating routes "for ease of marketing" urls. I was curious if the routes module in the CP had a way of creating these routes. I suspected not, because they link to a specific template not url. Thanks for your response Lindsey.

Comment: You're very welcome Aran! Unfortunately you're right, I don't think there's a way to easily manage routes to a non-static template. You could also setup some fancy routing up via the `config/routes.php` file, but that also denies the client of their "ease of marketing" desire.